# What Aromatic Fragrance that can be used in mouth fresher?

Tags: substitutions, flavor, food-preservation, food-identification

i am making mouth fresher(Paan Mukhwas in Hindi) in my home and for that one of ingredient is written as Aromatic Fragrance and i am confused what are the exactly.please could someone **pls tell what is the Aromatic Fragrance that can be used to make mouth freshener good in smell and last for 3-4 months** ?
Ingredients are: 
1.bettle nut 
2.Lime powder 
3.cardamom (green) powder 
4.Catechu powder 
**5.Aromatic flavou**r

Comment: What do you like? Mint? Rosewater? Cinnamon? Kitul? It's a pretty personal decision.

Comment: bettle (betel) nut and slaked lime Are likely to be taste killers. I'd try peppermint oil, or maybe clove oil. Sodium carbonate works with betel, without quite the same high pH shock as CaOH.

Comment: @WayfaringStranger will the paper mint oil Fragrance last for 3 months ?

Comment: Seal it. It's pretty stable.